# List index out of range in a text file using python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file, in which each line has words and spaces in between them. I need to extract only a few words in my text files. I wrote a small code to do the job but i got an error saying "**List index out of range**". I am not able to figure it out what has happened. Could some one shed some light on my issue?
Here is my code snippet
[Error Message in IDLE ide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yp56N.jpg),
[My text file contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZVss.jpg)

```
f2read = open('NEW1.txt','r+').readlines()
for line in f2read:
    if str(line.split()[0]) == '$TIME':
        pass
    elif line.split()[0].isdigit == True:
        print(line.split()[1]
```

)

If you look at the image in My Text File contents link, i have my sample text where there are values after a 10 digit mobile number. After running my code, it should print only the values.
For example:
$TIME = 1.0
8105346850 203,
9493915616 160
After running my code, it should print 203 and 160 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a single empty line in the file, `split()` will return an empty list and it will fail with this error. Are you sure there isn't such a line in the file?

In any case, you can verify that with the code:

```
f2read = open('NEW1.txt','r+').readlines()
for line in f2read:
    split_line = line.split()
    if len(split_line) > 0 and split_line[0].isdigit():
        print(split_line[1])
```

Comment: Thanks Ofer, i understood now the error message, Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it helps you